# Testing express routes with mocha - cannot store request in a variable

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mocha.js, supertest

Can someone explain to me why the following happens..

I have a code which tests express routes:

```
request = require 'supertest'
express = require 'express'
app = express()
Authentication = require("#{specDir}/../apps/authentication/routes")
authenticate = new Authentication app

describe 'authentication routes', ->
  describe 'GET', ->
    describe '/', ->
      describe 'user not logged in', ->
        requested = request(app).get('/').set('Accept', 'application/json')

        describe 'application/json', ->
          it 'sends error mesage', (done) ->
            request(app).get('/').set('Accept', 'application/json').end (err, res) ->
              expect(res.body).to.have.deep.property 'error.message', 'you need to log in'
              done()

          it 'sends 401 status', (done) ->
            request(app).get('/').set('Accept', 'application/json').end (err, res) ->
              expect(res.statusCode).to.equal 401
              done()
```

This code works as it should, the tests pass. But, if I swap this `request(app).get('/').set('Accept', 'application/json')` with the `requested` variable first test will pass, second will timeout.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `request` object can end only once. The first time you use the `requested.end(...` method to wait for the end, `requested` eventually ends. The second time, you wait forever (well, until the timeout occurs) because `requested` has *already* ended.

If you want to reuse the result among multiple tests (which seems to be the intent of saving `requested`) you could do something like this:

```
describe("user not logged in", function () {
    var res;

    before(function(done) {
        request(app).get('/').set('Accept', 'application/json').end(function (err, r) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            res = r;
            done();
        });
    });

    // You can use `res` from here on...
});
```

Comment: Didn't check it sooner. Was swamped with other stuff and since this is  for my own project it kinda got pushed to the side... Thanks for the help.